# What is the difference between std::condition_variable::wait_for and std::condition_variable::wait_until?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

The [reference I'm using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) explains the two in the following way:

- `wait_for` "blocks the current thread until the condition variable is woken up or after the specified timeout duration"
- `wait_until` "blocks the current thread until the condition variable is woken up or until specified time point has been reached"

What is the difference? Will `wait_until` spin so that the thread can continue exactly (more or less) when it is signaled, whereas `wait_for` just adds the thread back into scheduling at that point?

Comment: It's the difference between point-in-time and duration. Or between location and direction, if you will.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The difference is in how the wait duration is represented: `wait_for` takes a relative time ("wait for up to 10 seconds"), whereas `wait_until` takes an absolute time ("wait until 12:00 on October 30, 2012").

Compare the declarations of the time parameters:

```
// wait_for:
const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& rel_time

// wait_until:
const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& abs_time
```

Answer (score 33):

Your question and other answers have all repeated the difference; that `wait_for` waits for a specified amount of time and `wait_until` waits until a specified point in time, but the implications are not spelled out.

A `time_point` has an associated clock, and that clock is what's used to determine if the appropriate time has come. That means that clock adjustments are taken into account by the `wait_until` function. `wait_until(..., system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(10))` could end up waiting an hour and 10 seconds if the clock happens to be adjusted back by an hour before the wait is up.

A duration does not have any associated clock and therefore `wait_for` chooses its own clock. The standard specifies that it uses std::steady_clock, which cannot be adjusted and advances at a steady rate relative to real time. This means that `wait_for` will wait for the specified time regardless of any adjustments made to any clocks. `wait_for(..., std::chrono::seconds(10))` is guaranteed to wait 10 seconds (+ some time for the implementation to work and for scheduling issues).

There is no difference with regard to spinning vs. sleeping the thread; as `wait_for` is specified to behave as if it called `wait_until` with `steady_clock::now() + duration`.

---

Here's the part of the standard where this is spelled out:

#### [thread.req.timing] 30.2.4/2-4

> <sup>2</sup> Implementations necessarily have some delay in returning
>   from a timeout. Any overhead in interrupt response, function return,
>   and scheduling induces a “quality of implementation” delay, expressed
>   as duration *D*<sub>i</sub>. Ideally, this delay would be zero.
>   Further, any contention for processor and memory resources induces a
>   “quality of management” delay, expressed as duration *D*<sub>m</sub>.
>   The delay durations may vary from timeout to timeout, but in all cases
>   shorter is better.
>
> <sup>3</sup> The member functions whose names end in `_for` take an
>   argument that specifies a duration. These functions produce relative
>   timeouts. Implementations should use a steady clock to measure time
>   for these functions. Given a duration argument *D*<sub>t</sub>, the
>   real-time duration of the timeout is *D*<sub>t</sub> + *D*<sub>i</sub> + *D*<sub>m</sub>.
>
> <sup>4</sup> The member functions whose names end in `_until` take an
>   argument that specifies a time point. These functions produce absolute
>   timeouts. Implementations should use the clock specified in the time
>   point to measure time for these functions. Given a clock time point
>   argument *C*<sub>t</sub>, the clock time point of the return from timeout should be
>   *C*<sub>t</sub> + *D*<sub>i</sub> +  *D*<sub>m</sub> when the clock is not adjusted during the timeout. If the
>   clock is adjusted to the time *C*<sub>a</sub> during the timeout, the behavior
>   should be as follows:
>          — if *C*<sub>a</sub> > *C*<sub>t</sub>, the waiting function should wake
>   as soon as possible, i.e. *C*<sub>a</sub> + *D*<sub>i</sub> + *D*<sub>m</sub>, since the timeout is already
>   satisfied. [ *Note:* This specification may result in the total duration
>   of the wait decreasing when measured against a steady clock. *—end note*
>   ]
>         — if *C*<sub>a</sub> <= *C*<sub>t</sub>, the waiting function should not time out until
>   `Clock::now()` returns a time *C*<sub>n</sub> >= *C*<sub>t</sub>, i.e. waking at *C*<sub>t</sub> + *D*<sub>i</sub> + *D*<sub>m</sub>. [
>   *Note:* When the clock is adjusted backwards, this specification may
>   result in the total duration of the wait increasing when measured
>   against a steady clock. When the clock is adjusted forwards, this
>   specification may result in the total duration of the wait decreasing
>   when measured against a steady clock. *—end note* ]
> An implementation
>   shall return from such a timeout at any point from the time specified
>   above to the time it would return from a steady-clock relative timeout
>   on the difference between *C*<sub>t</sub> and the time point of the call to the
>   `_until` function. [ *Note:* Implementations should decrease the duration of the wait when the clock is adjusted forwards. *—end note* ]

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until: *the existing implementations convert timeout_time from Clock to std::chrono::system_clock and delegate to POSIX pthread_cond_timedwait so that the wait honors ajustments to the system clock, but not to the the user-provided Clock.*

Answer (score 5):

- `wait_for` will wait for a certain amount of time. It will for example wait for two seconds.
- `wait_until` will wait until some time is reached. It will for example wait until 23rd of July 2013 11:22:34 p.m. is reached on the clock.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one important difference in their usage as explained in Anthony Williams's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770):

Consider this example where a condition variable is waited with a timeout:

```
std::condition_variable cv;
bool done;
std::mutex m;

bool wait_loop()
{
    auto const timeout= std::chrono::steady_clock::now()+
    std::chrono::milliseconds(500);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    while(!done)
    {
       if(cv.wait_until(lk,timeout)==std::cv_status::timeout)
          break;
    }
    return done;
}
```

> This is the recommended way to wait for condition variables with a
>   time limit, if you’re not passing a predicate to the wait. This way,
>   the overall length of the loop is **bounded**. As you saw in section
>   4.1.1, you need to loop when using condition variables if you don’t pass in the predicate, in order to handle spurious wakeups. If you use
>   `wait_for()` in a loop, you might end up waiting almost the full length
>   of time before a spurious wake, and the next time through the wait
>   time starts again. This may repeat any number of times, making the
>   total wait time **unbounded**.

IMO, this is one such scenario where `wait_for` can't replace `wait_until` so easily, because of its resetting nature.

Comment: This is the real difference