# conditional variable wait_for() also runs on system clock internally?

Tags: c++

I was referring to cpp reference for [wait_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) and [wait_until](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13142514/4912037). I understand from both is that `wait_for()` SHOULD be immune to jumps in system time while `wait_until()` on system clock is susceptible to jumps in system time and may wait for incorrect duration because of that.

The notes on cpp reference (also a comment to that answer) points out that `wait_until()` internally uses system clock even if caller suggests (uses) steady clock. The code for dev toolset 9 on centos confirms the same:

```
  typedef chrono::system_clock        __clock_t;                                                                                                                                                                   
  typedef chrono::steady_clock        __steady_clock_t;
  .....
  template<typename _Clock, typename _Duration>
  cv_status
  wait_until(unique_lock<mutex>& __lock,
             const chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Duration>& __atime)
  {
    // DR 887 - Sync unknown clock to known clock.
    const typename _Clock::time_point __c_entry = _Clock::now();
    const __clock_t::time_point __s_entry = __clock_t::now();
    const auto __delta = __atime - __c_entry;
    const auto __s_atime = __s_entry + __delta;

    if (__wait_until_impl(__lock, __s_atime) == cv_status::no_timeout)
      return cv_status::no_timeout;
    // We got a timeout when measured against __clock_t but
    // we need to check against the caller-supplied clock
    // to tell whether we should return a timeout.
    if (_Clock::now() < __atime)
      return cv_status::no_timeout;
    return cv_status::timeout;
  }
```

What is interesting is that `wait_for()` internally uses `wait_until()` directly:

```
  template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
  cv_status
  wait_for(unique_lock<mutex>& __lock,                                                                                                                                                                                      
  const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
  {
    using __dur = typename __steady_clock_t::duration;
    auto __reltime = chrono::duration_cast<__dur>(__rtime);
    if (__reltime < __rtime)
      ++__reltime;
    return wait_until(__lock, __steady_clock_t::now() + __reltime);
  }
```

This makes no sense as `wait_until()` will get rid of the steady clock and `wait_for(0` too will become susceptible to system clock jumps. My understanding is that `wait_for()` SHOULD be immune to system time jumps.

Please help me understand what is happening here. What should I do if I want to wait on a conditional variable AND be immune from system time jumps?

Comment: You cannot be immune from spurious wake-ups.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. What are the causes for spurious wake-ups (other than jump in system time)?

Comment: Could be anything. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for the info. BTW for anyone looking for more info - in devset 10, the issue of wait_for ending up using system clock has been resolved and in devset 10 wait_until has a special definition that is used by wait_for to eliminate clock conversion from steady to system.